# IDE / Programming language for building cross-platform desktop application

Tags: windows, linux, cross-platform

I would like to make a cross-platform desktop application, and  I've experience in Visual Studio, VB.NET, and Databases.

Trying to make an Inventory and trading based desktop application that should works in Windows and Linux

What I need :

- Should work in windows, Linux, and mac(not necessary)
- Application need to communicate with internet(FTP,E-mail etc.)
- Should have reporting tools(like crystal report in visual studio)

---

NOTE : I've tried [**lazarus.freepascal**](http://www.lazarus.freepascal.org/)

Comment: Are you looking for an IDE or programming language?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt anything(IDE/Programming Lang.) am ready to learn new things. I think [this](http://archive09.linux.com/articles/53582) is useful, I just got it

Comment: Just curious, but why did you decide not to go with Lazarus? The sheer number of free VCL components would swing it for me.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [Qt](http://qt-project.org/) and [Java](https://java.com) platforms.

**Qt**

- Have its own [IDE](http://www.qt.io/download/) (It's very good)
- Based on C++
- [Signal slot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signals_and_slots) architecture.
- Cross-platform (even Android)

**Java**

- IDE: [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/), [Eclipse](https://eclipse.org/home/index.php), [IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/)
- Cross-platfrom (not supported for Android, but programming for Android is based on Java)

Answer (score 0):

[Eclipse](https://eclipse.org/home/index.php)/[NetBeans](http://netbeans.org)/[IntelliJ](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) IDEA for [Java](https://www.java.com/en/)

Any language that able has socket library, can connect to the network/internet.
There's a lot of options on using report in Java: [JaspeReport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JasperReports), [JReport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JReport), [DynamicReports](http://www.dynamicreports.org/), and [whole lot more](http://java-source.net/open-source/charting-and-reporting)

Comment: What about this http://archive09.linux.com/articles/53582, does this have any caveats ??

Comment: I don't think crystal report would work in monodevelop.. but lemme google first..

Comment: Ah i see, yes, its exists http://lists.ximian.com/pipermail/mono-devel-list/2010-December/036462.html

Comment: Is it a good idea to port already created .Net Application using mono in Linux ??

Comment: I believe Mono's community size is smaller than Java.

Comment: Maybe not all window application can be ported, but you can always try, there's a wizard for that http://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/winforms/porting-winforms-applications/

Answer (score 0):

You have the choice of Java, Python or Mono.  Personally I would suggest taking a look at python for this sort of requirement.

Comment: Is it easy to make python to exe ??

Comment: @DominicPretto For windows you can use py2exe or pyinstaller, for Mac there are equivalents I believe, Linux normally has python installed by default.

Answer (score 0):

Can use following IDE with wxWidgets (MFC like), which is cross platform C++ GUI toolkit:
http://www.anthemion.co.uk/dialogblocks/

There are also opensource alternatives available:
https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Tools

wxWidgets is also available in other programming languages, for example wxPython.